# Xamarin Android change orientation after ShowViewModel MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.ShowFragment exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a problem.. I have a Home page where I have a MvxListView  with some buttons... when I click on the button it change my viewmodel via ShowViewModel inside this SomeViewModel when I click on Back button I have bind here ShowViewModel (I need this instead of Close(this)...) it working and I'm back on the Home page... but problem is when after back on Home via back button I change orientation of Home page for example from Landscape to Portrait and now when I click on the button I have MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.ShowFragment exception.

When I'm using Close(this) instead of ShowViewModel it is working w/o error. It some solution how using ShowViewModel w/o this crash?

Crash report from HockeyApp:

**MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.ShowFragment**

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.ShowFragment(string tag, int contentId, Bundle bundle, bool forceAddToBackStack, bool forceReplaceFragment)
MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.Show(MvxViewModelRequest request, Bundle bundle, Type fragmentType, MvxFragmentAttribute fragmentAttribute)
MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Presenter.MvxFragmentsPresenter.ShowFragment(MvxViewModelRequest request)
MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Presenter.MvxFragmentsPresenter.Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ShowViewModel>b__0()
MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(Action action)
MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewDispatcher.ShowViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest request)
MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModelImpl(Type viewModelType, IMvxBundle parameterBundle, IMvxBundle presentationBundle)
MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel(Type viewModelType, IMvxBundle parameterBundle, IMvxBundle presentationBundle)
MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel(Type viewModelType, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> parameterValues, IMvxBundle presentationBundle)
MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(object parameterValuesObject, IMvxBundle presentationBundle)
MyMarkeeta.Core.ViewModels.ShopHolder.<get_ShowDailySalesCommand>b__46_0()
MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxCommand.Execute(object parameter)
MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Target.MvxViewClickBinding.ViewOnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(MonoMethod, object, object[], ref Exception)(wrapper managed-to-native)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)<d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)<d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object obj, object[] parameters)<d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0
MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription<TSource>.OnSourceEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
Android.Views.View.IOnClickListenerImplementor.OnClick(View v)<33e6e739ac344166b157e323586f11a1>:0
Android.Views.View.IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_v)<33e6e739ac344166b157e323586f11a1>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:8e0ee8ce-4942-437a-a709-093d1dea6c77 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick()View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30
android.view.View.performClick()View.java:5265
android.view.View$PerformClick.run()View.java:21534
android.os.Handler.handleCallback()Handler.java:815
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:104
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:207
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5728
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:789
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:679
```

Comment: I'd check on the lifecycle methods (VM -> Init, SaveToBundle, ReloadFromBundle,  Start; V -> OnCreate, OnCreateView, OnResume, etc) to not have a non-expected null value that is what is probably causing that exception

Comment: When you change the orientation of Home page,  the current Activity will be destroyed and restart. You can  prevent an Activity from being restarted when the orientation changes by setting ConfigurationChanges in the ActivityAttribute.https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/#Preventing_Activity_Restart